# Chartjs not working in IE8, issue with canvas element even after including excanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have been working on [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/).
It works fine in IE10 but when I change the document mode to IE8 it throws the below error

```
 Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'  line.html, line 43 character 2
```

I tried all the solutions suggested [here](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/89)

I included excanvas.js but no luck.

You can check the demo [here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) , visit this page and change the document mode to IE8. But the [parent site](http://www.chartjs.org/) works fine when we change browser mode and document mode to IE8. Please help me fix this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in my html i have this in my header

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../shared/js/excanvas/r73/excanvas.js?v=${BUILD.TAG}"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

in my html i have this for my body

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<body class="oldie">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]>
<body>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

then i use the chart.js like so (with jquery)

```
var isOldIE = $("body").hasClass("oldie");
var $canvas = this.$element.find("canvas");
var canvas = $canvas[0];
// kick old ie into creating fake canvas straight away
if(isOldIE) {
   canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
}
var chartObj = new Chart(canvas.getContext("2d"));
// do your stuff eg
chartObj.Pie(CHARTJS_DATA, CHARTJS_CONFIG);
```